# getting early EOF when using specific sequence of bytes

Tags: c, windows, cl, tcc

I have this example program which just reads stdin and prints the characters as ints:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    while (1) {
        char c = getchar();
        printf("%i\n", c);
        if (feof(stdin)) return 0;
    }
}
```

I've also generated input data using this Python script:

```
data = [71, 69, 71, 121, 118, 81, 51, 98, 51, 114, 119, 114, 108, 120, 33, 40, 22, 122, 125, 97, 88, 20, 81, 9, 22, 70, 70, 75, 89, 89, 90, 90, 88, 126, 20, 70, 9, 22, 77, 69, 71, 20, 70, 9, 22, 102, 78, 25, 103, 120, 124, 93, 102, 65, 30, 122, 96, 90, 20, 81, 9, 22, 91, 68, 31, 92, 105, 111, 20, 70, 9, 22, 99, 68, 124, 94, 97, 76, 17, 68, 89, 90, 20, 70, 9, 22, 76, 97, 91, 66, 105, 69, 20, 70, 9, 22, 16, 100, 20, 81, 9, 22, 77, 26, 93, 25, 111, 100, 64, 99, 20, 70, 9, 22, 73, 111, 79, 107, 102, 80, 127, 110, 28, 26, 108, 20, 70, 9, 22, 28, 93, 120, 75, 106, 124, 88, 76, 102, 78, 80, 24, 122, 20, 70, 9, 22, 121, 90, 78, 67, 73, 67, 20, 81, 9, 22, 90, 27, 76, 90, 20, 81, 9]

with open('data', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(bytes(data))
```

After compiling with either `cl.exe` from Visual Studio or `tcc` and running it:

`cat data | ./out.exe`

The output ends with:

```
9
22
77
-1
```

Which is only in like middle of the input data. Also, the output line count should be 165, but it is only 105 lines.

This example works perfectly fine on Linux, or on Windows with different inputs.
Why does this fail on this specific data? What did I do wrong?

Comment: On Windows, the byte value `26` corresponds to `Ctrl-Z` which is the end-of-file sequence for text input.

Comment: I thought that CTRL-Z was just interpreted by the console/terminal, not the program.

Comment: Not on Windows using the MSVC runtime. You need to read the input some other way, that bypasses `stdin` and its text-mode, some way to read the raw binary data.

Comment: On a different note, please remember that [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) actually returns an `int`. Which is crucial if you ever want to check the result against the `int` values `EOF` in a portable and standard way.

Comment: Windows recognises `26` (Ctrl-Z) as a file terminator in text mode. For legacy reasons. The last sequence was `9, 22, 77,` **`26`**. But if you create a text file in Windows now, it does not append the '26' like in the old days.

Comment: ... note that you printed the input value *before* you responded to `feof()`, which says you attempted to read past the end of the file. So MS doesn't consider the `26` to be data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert `stdin` to binary:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#  include <fcntl.h>
#  include <io.h>
#  define BINARY(fd) _setmode(fd, _O_BINARY)
#else
#  define BINARY(fd)
#endif

int main(void) {
    BINARY(0);
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
        printf("%i\n", ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this is only a problem on nefarious operating systems that deliberately corrupt your data. See the `#ifdef`.

Comment: I think it's necessary to call `_setmode` before you use the file the first time, as you've done in your example.